# What is an authentication strategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js, jwt

There doesn't appear to be a really clear explanation of what an authentication strategy is and what role it plays.

This is what I think it might be so far(please correct me if I'm wrong):

It appears that for each login type there is a strategy(google, facebook, local etc).

The strategy gets created then added to a passport object and the passport object is then used to sign a token which is used for a (un)specified time. However the username and password are not verified through jwt or passport initially.

Comment: Passport.js is base on a design pattern called Strategy. So it's creating different strategies (classes) for each given case (google, facebook, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An authentication strategy in passportjs isn't really that complicated -- it basically handles the 'authentication' of the user.

So, for instance, with the Passport LocalStrategy, it will take in a username/password, then check the database to see if those credentials are valid or not.

With stuff like the Google Login / Facebook Login Strategies, they'll simply use the Google Login API / Facebook Login API to redirect a user to Google / Facebook, have them accept the desired app permissions, then retrieve the resulting access token from the provider.

Strategies exist so that you can easily make passport authenticate a user in a number of different ways.

Comment: a couple of questions. If facebook creates the token, is our server storing that token like a local token? Then validating that token against the user requests? So, the secret in our 'facebook' app would be the secretOrKey? If we were to use facebook, wouldn't facebook control the expiration time?

Comment: It looks from reading the passport-facebook strategy on Github that all that strategy will do is give you back an access / refresh token from Facebook, then you must define your own callback to handle the user after that point. So it's up to you to write that logic.